# How to style div tag which its width as height? Like a square

Tags: javascript, css

I use **Bootstrap Framework** for building website. And I tried to search but it wasn't effective.
Futher more, I don't have much knowledge about **Javascript and CSS**.

An example code like this:

```
<div class="row">
<!-- Squares inline-block-->
<div class="col-md-2">
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
</div>
<!-- Squares inline-block-->
</div>
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: Are you trying to ensure that as the bootstrap grid columns resize, that their heights resize too?

Comment: Yes. With an aspect ratio of 1:1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's quite a simple method to create a div with an aspect ratio of 1:1 from pure CSS.

HTML:

```
<div class="width ratio">
    <div class="content">Aspect ratio 1:1</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.width {
width: 45%; /* Desired width size */
background: #000;
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
margin: 1%;
vertical-align: top;
}
.width:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
}
.ratio:before {padding-top: 100%;} /* keeps ratio at 1:1 */
.content {    
   position: absolute;
   top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
   font-size: 1.5rem;
   color: #fff;
}
```

This keeps the width the same as the height, although it would be a lot simpler to just set the width and height manually.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you give a class (let's call it 'square') to the div you want to be square:

```
<div class="row square">
```

Using CSS, you can set its height and width:

```
/*filename.css*/
.square{
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    background-color:green; /*to make it visible*/
}
```

To link the css file, put the following at the top of your html file:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css"> <!--I'm sure you've done this step :)-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="filename.css">
</head>
```

Learning CSS is easy. Give it a try!